# How to avaoid angular mat-panel postion change affect to matdialog

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have used [Matmenu](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview) and [MatDialogModule](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) in my angular project. I wanted to change the position of `mat-menu`. Furthermore, I did that using the following snippet adding to `.scss` file.

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {
    transform: translate(78%, 10%);
  }
```

However, this lead to change position of my Dialog Panels as well. I added class to `mat-menu` and tried to do the same thing and the result was not different.

```
 <mat-menu  #menu="matMenu" class="kebab-mat-menu" >
                  <button mat-menu-item (click)="deleteClinic(clinicData)">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                  </button>
  </mat-menu>
```

```
   .kebab-mat-menu{
       ::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane {
         transform: translate(78%, 10%) !important;
  }
}
```

My question is how to add this style only to `mat-menu` thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you use ::ng-deep. You can see in devtools that you have "css leak".

The solution i use(im not sure its right way) is to write the style for angular material in styles.css, and add special specification for material dialog etc.

You can read more about it in:

https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

They write that the solution is:
"You can define styles for these elements as global styles".